# How to copy code from vscode to OneNote without losing the formatting?

Tags: formatting, indentation, visual-studio-code, onenote

I want to keep a record of code I am working on by saving it in MicroSoft Office OneNote. When I copy and paste the code, all the indentations are gone.

```
def primeGenerator(primeList1, arr):
    for i in range(2, len(arr)):
        if arr[i]==0:
            primeList1.append(i)
            for j in range(i**2, len(arr), i):
                arr[j] = 1
```

Code shown above becomes like this

```
def primeGenerator(primeList1, arr):
for i in range(2, len(arr)):
if arr[i]==0:
primeList1.append(i)
for j in range(i**2, len(arr), i):
arr[j] = 1
```

I tried the solutions I found on the internet like

1. convert indentations to tabs in vscode
2. copy the code first in MS Word then in OneNote.

Comment: what if you replace the `space` by the Non-Break-Space, char(160), it is treated by many editors the same as a word char like `A`

Answer (score 2):

It isn't supported natively, however there are open source workarounds such as:
https://github.com/elvirbrk/NoteHighlight2016

Answer (score 2):

There is a OneNote `Settings/Options/Paste Options/`

Make sure that is set to `Keep Source Formatting`.

My pastes into OneNote retain indentation and syntax highlighting (I have `Editor: Copy with Syntax Highlighting` enabled).

Comment: For MacOS users, `OneNote/Preferences/Edit & View/Paste Options`

Answer (score 1):

I would advise against using Keep Source Formatting in OneNote under Settings.  I just notice that when Copying from Visual Studio Code into OneNote, OneNote replaces all space charactes (0x20) with NonBreak Space (0xA0).

To recreate the problem, copy something from VSC, and paste it [here](https://www.rapidtables.com/convert/number/ascii-to-hex.html).  Then Paste it into OneNote.  Then copy from OneNote, and paste it back in that same link. You will see that all the spaces (0x20) has been turn into NonBreak Space (0xA0), which Visual Studio Code does not like (CSS, JS, etc).

Instead use Keep Text Only

Answer (score 0):

On Windows

1. in VS Code change the settings `Editor: Insert Spaces` to checked.
2. before copying JS code from VS Code to OneNote find replace using
   regex:

   - Find: `\n\n`
   - replace: `\n\n\n`
   - replace all.
3. Cut and paste into OneNote.

Seems to be a bug in the copy paste of LF / CRLF defined text to OneNote.

Answer (score 0):

One and only easy solution.

**Copy the code from VSCode and Paste it in Word file**

**Next copy the code from the Word file to ONENOTE.**

And you will keep the code format.